# How to assign Service Principal to workspace programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have created a service principal in AAD and am able to assign to the workspace manually in https://app.powerbi.com/home

I want to assign the service principal to all the workspaces programmatically.

Is there any way to do it?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) and call [Update Group User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/update-group-user) to [add the service principal to the workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/update-group-user#example-for-giving-admin-access-right-to-a-service-principal):

Request:

```
PUT https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48/users
```

Request body:

```
{
  "identifier": "1f69e798-5852-4fdd-ab01-33bb14b6e934",
  "groupUserAccessRight": "Admin",
  "principalType": "App"
}
```

To use the API, you must authenticate yourself, for example with [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) or [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview). [Here is an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/automation/walkthrough-push-data-get-token) how to get an access token with MSAL:

```
private static async Task<string> GetToken()
{
   // TODO: Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory -Version 2.21.301221612
   // and add using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

   //The client id that Azure AD created when you registered your client app.
   string clientID = "{Client_ID}";

   //RedirectUri you used when you register your app.
   //For a client app, a redirect uri gives Azure AD more details on the application that it will authenticate.
   // You can use this redirect uri for your client app
   string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";

   //Resource Uri for Power BI API
   string resourceUri = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";

   //OAuth2 authority Uri
   string authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";

   //Get access token:
   // To call a Power BI REST operation, create an instance of AuthenticationContext and call AcquireToken
   // AuthenticationContext is part of the Active Directory Authentication Library NuGet package
   // To install the Active Directory Authentication Library NuGet package in Visual Studio,
   //  run "Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" from the nuget Package Manager Console.

   // AcquireToken will acquire an Azure access token
   // Call AcquireToken to get an Azure token from Azure Active Directory token issuance endpoint
   AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
   var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri)).Result.AccessToken;

   Console.WriteLine(token);
   Console.ReadLine();

   return token;
}
```

This token must be added to the request headers, when you call the API:

```
//Add token to the request header
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
```

Comment: Does this also work for managed identities?

Comment: @baouss Yes. Use the principalid of the managed identity.

Comment: @Andrej I can confirm that adding the SP this way worked, however it is also possible via the workspace's add members GUI. Unfortunately, I cannot yet confirm it working as intended, since in our tenant there is a setting restricting SP's use of the REST API unless whitelisted by a PBI admin. Had to register a security group for this and assign the MSIs as group members. The admin can then allow that group to access the API.